# Application testing for NAT traversal

Tags: javascript, html, web, webrtc

My question is simple:

I'm experimenting in WebRTC development. One of the major issues is NAT traversal. As a lone wolf developper, it is hard to test on 2 different static IP and the result is that , until one of my friends with the right browser and all the conditions required is online, I can't know if my app is really working or just in local.

Is there a way to use a proxy or something else to simulate 2 different static adresses on the same computer? How do I test my apps for NAT traversal on my own? If people with the same problem want to get in touch, I'll be happy to click on your stuff and feedback if you return the favor. Just comment or add my email and we can start working.

Comment: So your question is how to use more than one IP Address for HTTP requests?

Comment: There is two way I think : 1. Use a remote desktop to test your app externally 2. Use something like http://anonymouse.org that you can load your app from external but I don't know if it will works well with JavaScript requests, depend on relative URLs...

Comment: @meeWok : No. My question is, how do you test the NAT traversing capabilities of an app in development? :-)

Comment: @xShirase ever find out a solution?

Comment: Yeah, I found a colleague to be on the other side of the connection lol